# Partial HTML Selection Using Jsoup

Tags: html, web-scraping, jsoup

So I was wondering if there is a way to find the element that belongs to a specific String that you know exists on a HTML page as part of an attribute. The example is I know that "Apr-16-2015" is somewhere in an attribute on the HTML page. If I go look for it, it's part of the attribute title:

```
<a title="Apr-16-2015 5:04 AM"
```

However, I do not have the information about the exact time, i.e. the "5:04 AM". I was wondering if there is a way to partially search an attribute in order for it to return the full element.

This is my code:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Element links = lastPage.select("[title=\"Apr-16-2015\"]").first();
```

Again, it doesn't work because I did not enter the full attribute title, as given above. My question: "Is there any way to make this selector work by not entering the full information, as I will be unable to have the latter part of the attribute to my disposition?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it in the following way:

```
lastPage.select("[title^=\"Apr-16-2015\"]").first();
```

As described on JSoup Documentation:

> [attr^=value], [attr$=value], [attr*=value]: elements with attributes
>   that start with, end with, or contain the value, e.g. [href*=/path/]

References:
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark the question as solved by selecting the answer as solution.